# Replacing values in dataframe with 0s and 1s based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mask

I would like to filter and replace. For the columns with are lower or higher than zero and not NaN's, I would like to set for one and the others, set to zero.

```
mask = ((ts[x] > 0) 
        | (ts[x] < 0))
ts[mask]=1
ts[ts[x]==1]
```

I did this and is working but I have to deal with the values that do not attend this condition replacing with zero. 
Any recommendations? I am quite confusing, and also would be better to use *where* function in this case?

Thanks all!

**Sample Data**

```
    asset.relativeSetpoint.350
0                        -60.0
1                          0.0
2                          NaN
3                        100.0
4                          0.0
5                          NaN
6                       -120.0
7                       -245.0
8                          0.0
9                        123.0
10                         0.0
11                      -876.0
```

**Expected result**

```
    asset.relativeSetpoint.350
0                            1
1                            0
2                            0
3                            1
4                            0
5                            0
6                            1
7                            1
8                            0
9                            1
10                           0
11                           1
```

Comment: `ts[mask]`, why are you assigning this to 1? Can you provide some input and expected output? What exactly is your goal?

Comment: @coldspeed I will after do a graph based on the time certain parameter was activated and the time that it was not (with zero). Also, my others values are either NaN or already zero

Comment: Maybe, this would work? `df[:] = mask.values[:, None].repeat(df.shape[1], axis=1).astype(int)`

Comment: @coldspeed Yes, I have tried just now. I am getting a weird result probably doing something wrong. I will update the question, not that is hard but now I am wondering if I am using it correctly.

Comment: Like I said, please provide some input and expected output (as text). It is hard to determine your problem just by staring at your code.

Comment: That's fine. Just 5-20 rows would be enough. Can you show your expected output, or explain what you want the output to look like for this data?

Comment: I would like to filter and replace. For the columns with are lower or higher than zero and not NaN's, I would like to set for one and the others, set to zero. @coldspeed not sure why the mask did not worked

Comment: Then, that means the accepted answer is incorrect, because it does not account for NaNs (those are also set to 1). See my answer for details.

Comment: Cleaned up your question a bit. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by applying a logical AND on the two conditions and converting the resultant mask to integer.

```
df

    asset.relativeSetpoint.350
0                        -60.0
1                          0.0
2                          NaN
3                        100.0
4                          0.0
5                          NaN
6                       -120.0
7                       -245.0
8                          0.0
9                        123.0
10                         0.0
11                      -876.0
```

```
(df['asset.relativeSetpoint.350'].ne(0) 
 & df['asset.relativeSetpoint.350'].notnull()).astype(int)

0     1
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     0
5     0
6     1
7     1
8     0
9     1
10    0
11    1
Name: asset.relativeSetpoint.350, dtype: int64
```

---

The first condition `df['asset.relativeSetpoint.350'].ne(0)` gets a boolean mask of all elements that are not equal to 0 (this would include <0, >0, and NaN).

The second condition `df['asset.relativeSetpoint.350'].notnull()` will get a boolean mask of elements that are not NaNs.

The two masks are ANDed, and converted to integer.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `apply`?

```
df[COLUMN_NAME] = df[COLUMN_NAME].apply(lambda x: 1 if x != 0 else 0)
```

Comment: @Mayra It is the worst possible solution to a problem when there are better methods out there. Like I said twice, please provide some data, and someone will give you a better answer.

Comment: you are right! I am not sure how to bring the whole data to the code description cause but I tried to exposure some. I don't understand why the mask is not working together with where function.